# How can I use two listview in a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, scrollview

There is a layout as follows. Two listView and on their headers with image and text. There are buttons at the bottom. My problem is, If the first listview is to height, other listview and buttons does not appear. I wanted to make a scrollview that contains the headers and the ListViews, but did not work.
How can I do?
Thanks

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/Dep"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/Orange"
    android:gravity="center"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:text="@string/Continue"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @realuser Also in your other questions; at least give some comments to useful answers, so that others can take benefit of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows:

I used this code in my activity for listview:

```
HelperScrollView.getListViewSize(listview);
```

This is the class:

```
public class HelperScrollView 
{
public static void getListViewSize(ListView myListView) {
    ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
    if (myListAdapter == null) {
        //do nothing return null
        return;
    }
    //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
        View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
  //setting listview item in adapter
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount()));
    myListView.setLayoutParams(params);

}
```

}

You can use a listview into scrollview in your layout.

Answer (score 2):

ListView are scrollable views in android, if you want to include two Listviews on single screen, you can do by fixing height of parents of these views. for Example, in below code, I have fixed the height of linearlayouts containing listviews, you can use weight to arrange all the views according to screen height.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/Dep"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/Orange"
        android:gravity="center"
         >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon2" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:text="@string/Continue"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout

>
```

Answer (score 0):

by this way you can use two listview...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_payment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_bank"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lst_payment"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout
```

Comment: I think giving fixed height is bad idea, as it will not look good for different screen sizes and resolutions, rather than that weight should be used

Comment: because you want to get both listview's click..that's why i set the fixed height

Comment: you are right @Why and How. Although the screen is large, the listview  has scrolling. That's not good look. Another solution must be.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for second list view not appearing is that you have not set orientation of your Linear layout. Set its orientation to vertical it will appear.

Answer (score 0):

i have no idea why you need two listviews in one activity, but the code above could help only if you dont specify the listview height. i believe you could make a more fancy and  cool list view using the MergeAdpter [take a look here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge/tree/master/src)